# Pandas dataframe- Column names not aligned properly

Tags: pandas, dataframe

small problem here- more an aesthetic issue with Pandas.  Basically- I am just reading a table (read_html) from the internet, and then printing it out.  The column names are not aligned-- on a different row.

```
import pandas as pd

standings = pd.read_html("http://soccerleague.org", index_col=0)
standings_table = standings[0][["PTS", "PF", "PA"]]
print(standings_table)
```

This prints out:

```
                    PTS  PF  PA
Team                           
Spain                20  48  16
France               15  41  26
Germany              13  46  34
United Kingdom       10  34  33
Brazil                8  33  42
Argentina             4  22  35
Uruguay               4  23  34
Russia                2  20  47

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The table is correct. But, I would like the PTS, PF, PA column names **to be on the same row** as "Team" column name.  I cant find any info on this , any help would be great !

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to align column name:

```
standings_table = standings_table.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though 'Team' is counted as an element, not a column title, perhaps

```
standings_table = wdl_standings[0][["Team","PTS", "PF", "PA"]]
```

would work?

Comment: I set the "Team" column to be the index in `index_col=0` .  But your code does help if I remove the index_col statement.  But then I get a pesky 0-7 index on the left that I also dont want in the table see http://imgur.com/a/Q9wF8